How to find the amount of leisure time and the good consumed in a two-person and one-good economy?
Question:
Suppose an economy consists of two price-taking people, “a” and “b.” Person a has available 1
unit of “time” which he divides between rest $R(a)$ and labour $L(a)$. Person b has available 1 unit of “time” which he divides between rest $R(b)$ and labour $L(b)$. Good “$x$” is produced by many competitive firms according to a linear production function $F(L)=L$ where $L$ is the labour. Let the amount of good $x$ consumed by Person a be $x(a)$ and the amount of good $x$ consumed by Person b be $x(b)$. Let $X = x(a) + x(b)$.
Suppose production of $x$ causes air pollution which decreases the utility of Person b but not of Person a (perhaps because Person a lives far away from the source of the air pollution). The
utility functions of the two individuals are
$ua = x(a)*R(a)$
$ub = x(b)*R(b) - X$.
Suppose that Person b always sees “$X$” as exogenous; he never thinks of X as being $x(a) +x(b)$ (even though it is), and therefore he never considers the effect of his own consumption of x on the amount of air pollution. (You may think about “person a” and “person b” as “representative
consumers”, i.e., a collection of many small consumers whose individual decisions have little
effect on aggregate variables). Take the price of labour to be $1.
Find $x(a)$, $R(a)$, $x(b)$, and $R(b)$.
My Attempt:
As Person b is exogenous, we can consider its utility function without X because he ignores it and won't affect how he thinks will maximize his utility. From this step, however, I was stuck. I suppose that they consume the exact amount that they produce, but I cannot confirm the validity (they may not be able to afford all of the products they produce). Additionally, I am not sure about the price of the good, so it becomes challenging for me to solve it. My primitive guess is that each person would split their time half-half, but I feel that this is incorrect.
Thank you in advance and I really appreciate your help!

If you want to find equilibrium you start by asking: What equations must hold in equilibrium? Then you most likely get a system of non-linear equation you can solve for the endogenous variables.

Hi Jesper, to determine the price of the good, I am thinking of determining the demand and supply. The supply equation should be L(a)+L(b) without doubt, but what would be the demand function though? If I am able to find that, I think I can tackle the rest of the question more easily. Thanks!
